# Nuxtjs: Scss partials are not importing to the page

Tags: css, import, sass, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am new to scss in Nuxtjs. I have added all the css to assets folder, and also modified nuxt.config.js as below.

```
assets/
  sass/
   project/
      element/
      _input.scss
      _tables.scss
      _model.scss
      mixins/
      _buttons.scss
      _lables.scss
      _navbar.scss
      _table-row.scss
    _cards.scss
    _inputs.scss
    _tables.scss
    _pages.scss
    _variables.scss
    _mixins.scss
  main.css
```

My main css file

```
@import "project/variables";
@import "project/mixins";

@import "project/element/input";
@import "project/element/tables";
@import "project/element/model";

@import "project/mixins/buttons";
@import "project/mixins/lables";
@import "project/mixins/navbar";
@import "project/mixins/table-row";

@import "project/cards";
@import "project/inputs";
@import "project/tables";
@import "project/pages";
```

My vue files:
[image]

I have done this to my nuxt.config.js.

```
styleResources: {
      scss: [
          __dirname +  '/assets/sass/project.scss',
      ]
  },
```

But I don't understand what is wrong with the scss. I get basic layouts but I cannot get partials on a page. Is there anything with the pages/components folder structure to load imports?